# Iterating through large file and appending chunks on disk taking up all memory

Tags: python, csv, pandas, bigdata

I have a file approximately 5GB compressed (32GB Uncompressed) with gzip and has approx 200+ Million rows. I have the below pandas code going through chunks and applying some processing and saving as one csv iteratively. I don't understand however why this gradually uses up all of my RAM before it completes (32GB RAM EC2). I was assuming that I am avoiding having to use up RAM by just saving on disk. Am I doing something wrong or mis-understanding this process? Is there a much better way to do this?

```
chunker = pd.read_table('filename.txt.gz', compression='gzip', 
    delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=10000, iterator=True, header=None)

for chunk in chunker:
    process chunk

with open(fout, 'a') as filename:
    chunk.to_csv(filename)
    filename.close()
```

Comment: Most likely you're inadvertently holding on to references to the objects in each `chunk`.  It's impossible to tell without seeing your code, though; what you've provided is, in the crucial spot, pseudo-code.  But you could determine whether your processing is at fault by removing it:  simply iterate over the file with `pandas` and write each chunk to disk without the processing step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following things:

- Increase memory usage by `low_memory = False`

  ```
  chunker = pd.read_table('filename.txt.gz', compression='gzip',\ 
            low_memory = False, delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=10000,\
            iterator=True, header=None)
  ```
- And also increase the memory limit for each process set by the OS.